# I can't user Oracle DataAccess in Silverlight?

Tags: database, oracle, silverlight

I'm creating a silverlight web app that I want to connect to a oracle database, get some data and present some pretty charts.

I thought I could add the OracleDataAccess.dll to the silverlight project (reference) but I get popups saying it cant add that.
So I created a Lib, thinking I could add the dll there and make som static functions to what I need and then add this project to the silverlight project... but no, I cant do that either.

So how can I query my Oracle database (11.2g) from Silverlight?

Comment: No, there is no way to get data from any type of database without the use of a webservice from silverlight

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a web service that does the actual communication with Oracle.

Silverlight doesn't have direct access to the database drivers.

Comment: Hmm... and then the silverlight polls data from it? any good tutorial for a simple web service for asp.net?